# Schoology API understanding

Tags: python, api

I can get to the user information using the API but I cannot access course information. Can someone explain what I need to do to make the correct call for course information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was seeing 403 for `/users` or `/sections`. Then I checked the [Schoology PHP library](https://github.com/schoology/schoology_php_sdk/blob/01d0b284ae2e49605166e48d0c0610834a8d7612/SchoologyApi.class.php#L144) to figure this out:

Make the GET to `/app-user-info` to find your `api_uid`. Mine looks like an integer.

Then check the [API Sample Apps](https://developers.schoology.com/app-platform/sample-apps/course-listing)...

Use that `uid` to list your sections by GET `/users/<uid>/sections`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer these questions is to try it in Postman. Highly recommended.